# ObservableCollection<T>(List<T>)

Tags: c#, observablecollection

In msdn you can read: "Initializes a new instance of the ObservableCollection class that contains elements copied from the specified list."

But I don't understand this behaviour:

I have got a class Person.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Firstname + " " + Lastname;
    }
}
```

Now i create a List of persons.
Then i create an ObservableCollection that should contain copied elements from the list.

Then I change one person in the list, and one person in the ObservableCollection.
Both changes are reflected in both collections. Why?

Finally I add one person to the list and one to the OC.
The added items are only reflectet in the related collection

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<Person> PersonList{ get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<Person> PersonObservableCollection { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FillCollections();

        listbox1.ItemsSource = PersonList;
        listbox2.ItemsSource = PersonObservableCollection;            
    }


    private void FillCollections()
    {
        PersonList = LoadDataPerson();
        PersonObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>(PersonList);

        // Adding a person to the List.
        PersonList.Add(new Person() { Firstname = "added to List",});

        // Adding a person to the ObservableCollection.
        PersonObservableCollection.Add(new Person() { Firstname = "added to Observable Collection" });


        // Changing then name of the first person in the List
        Person p1 = PersonList[0];
        p1.Lastname = "changed in List";

        // Changing the name of the second person in the ObservableList
        Person p2 = PersonObservableCollection[1];
        p2.Lastname = "changed in ObservableCollection";
    }


    private List<Person> LoadDataPerson()
    {
        List<Person> personen = new List<Person>();
        personen.Add(new Person() { Firstname = "John"});
        personen.Add(new Person() { Firstname = "Will"});
        personen.Add(new Person() { Firstname = "Sam" });
        return personen;
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ObservableCollection.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ObservableCollection"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="listbox1"/>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="listbox2"/>

</Grid>
```

The output looks like this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJi83.png)

Comment: Do you understand how [reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) work?  In particular, do you understand that a list of reference-type objects is actually a list of *references* to uniquely identifiable objects that live elsewhere in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In msdn you can read: "Initializes a new instance of the ObservableCollection class that contains elements copied from the specified list."

That is true, but what is being copies are the elements, not their content - meaning the reference for the elements.

So now you have two collection that have the same elements.
When you will ask an element from the list or the observableCollection you will get a reference to the same instance of person.
So changing it would, obviously reflect in both.

When you add a new item, you add it to a specific collection and it won't be copied to the other one.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation could be clearer there.  For a value type, like `int`, it's obvious what "copied" means in:

> Initializes a new instance of the `ObservableCollection<T>` class that contains elements copied from the specified list.

In your case however, you have a reference type.  It's this reference that's being copied between the two lists, so both lists are pointing at the same underlying object, meaning any updates are seen in both.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a fault of the documentation: isn't it incumbent on the programmer to understand that a `List<T>`, where `T` is a reference type, is actually a list of *references* of type `T`?  It's fundamental to the .NET type system.  If every document concerning (or even just *possibly* concerning!) reference types had to cover this concept, the documentation would become unsustainably dense.

Comment: @phoog Oh absolutely, you do need to understand the type system.  I do wonder if there would be a better way to phrase _"elements copied"_ though

Comment: Good point.  They could add a couple of words there to remind readers that *elements* may be references, and link to the relevant material so novice readers can pursue it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

So if you look at the [source code for this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs,281923b8611114ec) the underlying list is being manipulated.

```
    protected virtual void InsertItem(int index, T item) {
        items.Insert(index, item);
    }
```

that is just one example, with `items` being a private field:

```
public class Collection<T>: IList<T>, IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    IList<T> items;
    [NonSerialized]
    private Object _syncRoot;

    public Collection() {
        items = new List<T>();
    }

    public Collection(IList<T> list) {
        if (list == null) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.list);
        }
        items = list;
    }
```

As you can clearly see when you modify both collections (the observable one and your original one), the changes will be reflected in both.

All the `ObservableCollection` is doing over the top is proxying the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.